# '.class' expected when trying to pass a double Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

I'm a newbie of Java, and while studying it I found out an exercise who killed my brain for almost 7 hours. I tried everything I knew, I read the chapter of the book once again, I've googled for an answer for hours, and even used the Search button here, but nothing helped me. I can't understand what the heck is wrong with line 26:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Esercizio {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner tastiera = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Scrivi un intero per la lunghezza dell'Array.");
        System.out.println("");

        int lunghezzaArray = 0;
        lunghezzaArray = tastiera.nextInt();

        double[] valore = new double[lunghezzaArray];

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Ora scrivi i numeri che vuoi dentro, possibilmente in ordine crescente.");
        System.out.println("");

        for (int i = 0; i < valore.length; i++) {
            valore[i] = tastiera.nextDouble();}

        boolean risultato = true;

        risultato = strettamenteMaggiore(valore[]); // Here is the line!

        System.out.println("Uscira' True o False? Risultato = " + risultato);

    }

    public static boolean strettamenteMaggiore(double[] valore) {

        boolean risultato = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < valore.length; i++) {
            if (valore[i] < valore[i + 1]) {
                risultato = true;}
            else
                risultato = false;
        }

        return risultato;
    }

}
```

The program is in Italian, but I guess it doesn't matter, variables and stuff names are just, names. 
Any idea of what's wrong with the code? This is the first time I encounter this error with Arrays and Methods.

Edit:
The exercise asks to write a static method called 'strettamenteCrescente(double[] in)' which returns "true" if every value of the array supplied to the input is greater than the value that precedes it. Else, "false".

Comment: What do you think `strettamenteMaggiore(valore[]);` does? Why do you think so? What is `valore[]`?

Comment: Just remove the `[]` from `valore` when calling `strettamenteMaggiore`.

Comment: Yes! It works! Finally! I still don't understand why, but now I can go on and finish my program! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Balduz has it right.  Just remove the brackets `[]`.  In *Java*, brackets are used to declare the array, as in `double[] valore`, or to refer to an element of the array, as in `valore[i]`.  To refer to the array object itself, you just use the array name.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a POSITION of the array to the method, but the method is expecting the whole array.

The solution is:

```
risultato = strettamenteMaggiore(valore); // Here is the linee
```

instead of

```
risultato = strettamenteMaggiore(valore[]); // Here is the line!
```